# Laravel phpunit api return 405

Tags: php, laravel, api, phpunit

I can not test the api with phpunit testing. I have created a testcase and a test route. But it gives me an error like `Expected status code 200 but received 405.`

My User controller test:-

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\API\Medical\V1;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

use App\User;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLogin()
    {

        $user = User::find(1);

        $response = $this->actingAs($user,'api')->json('POST','/api/test');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I have not done anything to testCase base class.

My api routes:-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('/test',function(){
    return response()->json([
        'success'=>true
    ]);
});
```

But this route is working on postman. When i change http method to `GET` it gives me my default route on `routes/web.php`. How to get my actual json to my testcase? thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a CORS issue. For a quick check try calling ` $this->withoutMiddleware();` at the beginning of your test.

Comment: @FrankProvost :-( Still same the error.

Comment: can you try to type `php artisan route:list` in your project root console and show what is returned for the /test route?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

The project was raised in docker. In the .env file, you need to write:

> APP_URL=http://localhost